# Rails: creating column references without foreign keys

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

In Rails 4 models, I want to model an employee-department relationship. An employee belongs_to a department and a department has_many employees. Can I create a department_id reference in the employee table without making it a foreign key?

The reason I want to do this is that I suspect this impacts the record-locking behavior in MySQL, which is the database I am using, and it may be causing random errors when I perform concurrent updates from multiple threads in my Rails application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. If you're using Rails 4.2 and using [`references`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/TableDefinition.html#method-i-references) or [`add_reference`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_reference) within your migrations, just set the `:foreign_key` option to false.

You can also take the approach described by @user1063998 and just add an integer column called `department_id` to your employees table although in that case, I would recommend also adding an index for this column.

Answer (score 1):

Rails by default does not add a foreign key constraint at the database level.

Using a migration you can simply add an integer column to the employee table called `department_id`. If you need to mimic the behaviour of a foreign key constraint, you can use validations on the model.